# How to synthesize this python function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code more compact. I think there is a part that can be nicely reduced but am not sure how to do it. I put a comment inside the code copied below for you to find it fast.

The code is the next one:

```
def change_to_mop_gen(infile, namedir="",charge=0, gnorm=None, separate=True, hamiltonian="PM6", calctype="opt", multiplicity="singlet", eps=None, cycles=None):
#armado de la salida
    if calctype=="thermo(298,298,0)":
        calctype1="thermo"
    else: 
        calctype1=calctype
    outfile=infile.split(".")[0] + "-" + calctype1 + "-" + hamiltonian

#~ here comes the set of if / else sentences i think could be reduced

    if gnorm !=None:
        gnorm="gnorm=" + str(gnorm)
    else:
        gnorm= " "
    if cycles!=None:
        cycles="cycles="+str(cycles)
    else:
        cycles=""
    if separate==True:
        outfile=outfile + "_*.mop"
    else:
        outfile=outfile + ".mop"
    if eps !=None:
        eps="eps=" + str(eps)
    else:
        eps = ""  

    #~here it ends

    keywords = "-xk '%s  %s %s %s %s %s charge=%i'"%(cycles, hamiltonian, calctype, multiplicity, eps, gnorm, charge)
    #change directory of outfile
    if namedir!="":
        outfile= namedir + "/" + outfile
    return change_format(infile,outfile, keywords)
```

Any help would be good.

Comment: I think you want to be in stackoverflow not in tex.stackexchange. And also use `if gnorm is None:` for `None` comparisons

Comment: `gnorm = " " if gnorm is None else  "gnorm=" + str(gnorm)`

Comment: @percusse yes i am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up and corrected your code here:

```
gnorm= ("gnorm=" + str(gnorm)) if gnorm is not None else ""
cycles="cycles="+str(cycles) if cycles is not None else ""
outfile=(outfile + "_*.mop") if separate else (outfile + ".mop")
eps=("eps=" + str(eps)) if eps is not None else ""
```

This is how to write your methods shorthand. Also you should never evaluate that a boolean is == to true, the boolean itself is the condition. Also you do is or is not none not equals evaluations.

Comment: Thank you, it helps. But that is not exactly what i asked.  I reformulate: is there a way to put all `if` and `is not None else` once? Since gnorm, cycles and eps lines are similar..

Comment: Considering they are separate variables getting evaluated separately, it doesn't really make sense to condense them all into one thing. If you wanted to make it look less cluttered, you could make a method where you send the variable and then do that evaluation but considering it's one line of code as it is, I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Could you explain in the answer, briefly, Why should not i use !=?

Comment: None isn't a value, it's an absence of value. So you use is to check whether the variable is absent of value rather than an equals sign.